# Giving file permission on creation of a text file

Tags: c#

Create a text file using C# program so that on opening the file in explorer it should ask for Administrator privilages (Only a person with administrator privilages can open the file).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        File.Create(@"E:\test.txt");
        FileSecurity Security = File.GetAccessControl(@"E:\test.txt");
        SecurityIdentifier Everybody = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        SecurityIdentifier Admin = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
        Security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Everybody, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
        Security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Admin, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
        File.SetAccessControl(@"E:\test.txt", Security);
    }
```

Comment: Okay. So what have you tried?

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: you should revoke all of the other access rights.

Comment: @Daniel I am not able to identify which all I have to allow and which all I have to deny.

Comment: @neo, nice explanation of access rights here https://www.codeproject.com/reference/871338/accesscontrol-filesystemrights-permissions-table

Comment: Please actually ask a question. Please read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to clearly state your problem, how you tried to solve it and what exactly does not work. Right now, your post looks like you copypasted an exercise from a homework assignment.

Comment: @neo, problem of your code - administrators are everyone too and restrictive permissions override lenient permissions , actually to delete this file you need permission from creator/owner. The solution can be to call `SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false)` on your access control  object to prevent inheritance and than  add your allow rule for administrators. Am to lazy to check